# Clear element.classList

Tags: javascript, dom

[`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) is of [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMTokenList) type.

Is there a method to clear this list?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I'm not aware of a "method" in the sense of a "function" associated with `classList`. It has `.add()` and `.remove()` methods to add or remove individual classes, but you can clear the list in the sense of removing all classes from the element like this:

```
element.className = "";
```

Comment: When I try `element.classList = ""` in Safari (Version 9.1.1), I get an error:

`TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.`

Comment: https://jsperf.com/classname-vs-classlist-for-clear - on my box, it's the fastest solution on Chrome.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I was looking at Phil's comment. I'll delete my comments

Comment: Please note that this version will not work in IE 11 or older as IE conforms to ecma 5 standard of no direct access. Use the answer below.

Comment: @NeilMasters - [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) can be set, and that was true in ECMA 5 too and worked in older IE. Note the difference between `className` and `classList`.

Comment: unless I'm making a mistake, this can't be used on SVG nodes, at least in firefox. `className` is read-only. This works: `node.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', '')`

Comment: On Edge and SVG, setAttribute( 'class', '' ) also is OK

Answer (score 78):

With ES6 and the spread operator, this is a breeze.

```js
element.classList.remove(...element.classList);
```

This will spread the list items as arguments to the remove method.
Since the `classList.remove` method can take many arguments, they all are removed and the `classList` is cleared.

Even though it is readable it is not very efficient. @Fredrik Macrobond's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040297/clear-element-classlist/55450927#answer-43640203) is faster.
View different solutions and their test results at [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-clear-classlist).

Answer (score 16):

```
var classList = element.classList;
while (classList.length > 0) {
   classList.remove(classList.item(0));
}
```

Comment: https://jsperf.com/classname-vs-classlist-for-clear - on my box, it's the fastest solution on IE10/11 (and probably on Edge too)

Comment: I don't understand why `classList.item(0).remove();` does not work.

Comment: @Shayan `.item(0)` gives you the first class name, you'd be calling `.remove()` on a string

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way to do it:

```
element.setAttribute("class", "")
```

Comment: IMO this is the proper way to do it, because other methods won't show the change in the "Elements" tab on browser's Developer Tools, but this one does.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays, `classList` is preferred to `(remove|set)Attribute` or `className`.
Pekaaw's answer above is good, 1 similar alternative is to set the `DomTokenList.value`

```
elem.classList.value = ''
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to simply remove the class attribute:

```js
elem.removeAttribute('class')
```

Comment: This seems to be super straightforward and probably fast?

Comment: @JoshuaDance While it may be that, perhaps the poster *needs* the attribute, in which it'd just be faster to simply set the attribute, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using `className` as `classList` could result in faster DOM updates.

The `remove()` method of `DOMTokenList` (which is what `classList` is) can take multiple arguments - each a string of a classname to remove ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)). First you need to convert the `classList` to a plan array of classnames. Some people use `Array.prototype.slice()` to do that, but I'm not a fan and I *think* a for loop is faster in most browsers - but either way I have nothing against for loops and the slice often feels like a hack to me. Once you have the array you simply use `apply()` to pass that array as a list of arguments.

I use a utility class I wrote to accomplish this. The first method is the one you are looking for, but I'm including slightly more for your reference.

```
ElementTools.clearClassList = function(elem) {
    var classList = elem.classList;
    var classListAsArray = new Array(classList.length);
    for (var i = 0, len = classList.length; i < len; i++) {
        classListAsArray[i] = classList[i];
    }
    ElementTools.removeClassList(elem, classListAsArray);
}
ElementTools.removeClassList = function(elem, classArray) {
    var classList = elem.classList;
    classList.remove.apply(classList, classArray);
};
ElementTools.addClassList = function(elem, newClassArray) {
    var classList = elem.classList;
    classList.add.apply(classList, newClassArray);
};
ElementTools.setClassList = function(elem, newClassArray) {
    ElementTools.clearClassList(elem);
    ElementTools.addClassList(elem, newClassArray);
};
```

Please note that I have not thoroughly tested this in all browsers as the project I am working on only needs to work in a very limited set of modern browsers. But it *should* work back to IE10, and if you include a shim (https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) for classList, it *should* work back to IE7 (and also with SVGs since Eli Grey's shim adds support for SVG in unsupported browsers too).

An alternative approach I considered was to loop backwards through the `classList` and call `remove()` on classList for each entry. (Backwards because the length changes as you remove each.) While this should also work, I figured using the multiple arguments on `remove()` could be faster since modern browsers may optimize for it and avoid multiple updates to the DOM each time I call remove() in a for loop. Additionally both approaches require a for loop (either to build a list or to remove each) so I saw no benefits to this alternative approach. But again, I did *not* do any speed tests.

If somebody tests speeds of the various approaches or has a better solution, please post.

**EDIT**: I found a bug in the shim which stops it from correctly adding support to IE11/10 for multiple arguments to `add()` and `remove()`. I have filed a [report](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/issues/54) on github.

Comment: Don't guess what's faster, measure what's faster!

Comment: Be my guest :-) That is why I said, "If somebody tests speeds of the various approaches or has a better solution, please post." My point was just to present alternative approaches that should be considered by people who find this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: on my setup, Chrome optimizes `className = ""` to 5x the speed of `classList.remove()`, FF does both sluggishly and at about the same speed, IE-on-Chrome favours classList iteration/removal.