# Change A Class Name to a empty name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm noob and I need help.
I want to change the Class name when I enter the Web

Here is the Html :

```
<div class="row innerbodypanel">
    <form name="AGX" id="AGX" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

I want to change the Class (row innerbodypanel) to a empty like Class=""

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-to-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear element.classList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040297/clear-element-classlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
use jQuery removeClass
$(".innerbodypanel").removeClass("row innerbodypanel")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row innerbodypanel">
<form name="AGX" id="AGX" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `className` property to change it to an empty string (`''`)

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('.row.innerbodypanel').className = '';
}
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: red;
}

.innerbodypanel {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row innerbodypanel">test!</div>
<form name="AGX" id="AGX" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off"></form>
<button class="btn">click me !</button>
```

Comment: Isn't `className` the string version of `classList`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl i guess both works, but `className` might be more intuitive to use with a string. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div id="A" class="row innerbodypanel">
   <form name="AGX" id="AGX" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</div>

$("#A").removeClass("innerbodypanel")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(() =>
{
    $("div").removeClass("row innerbodypanel");
});
```

This will remove the class when the entire page is loaded. Thus, there is no danger that the removeClass function will be executed before the div element is loaded.
Also you will maybe need an id for the div because the "div" selector is very generic.